# How to call parse_qs to save dictionary values in a String instead of List?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have the following line to parse URL parameters:

```
url="?firstParam=First&secondParam="
params=parse_qs(urlparse(url).query, keep_blank_values=True)
```

The result is a dictionary with the following values:

```
{'firstParam': ['First'], 'secondParam': ['']}
```

As I understand, dictionary values are Lists in this case. Is there a way I could call parse_qs to store them as strings?

Comment: Is there anything you're asking that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024143/how-to-stop-python-parse-qs-from-parsing-single-values-into-lists) doesn't already cover?

Comment: I think that clears things up. Thanks for the link. Sorry for the duplicate.