# How to allow any arbitrary query parameters using FastAPI and Swagger?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, query-string

**Note**: This question is different from the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279710/fastapi-variable-query-parameters), in that I need it to work with Swagger.

Given a FastAPI `GET` endpoint, I want to allow any arbitrary set of URL parameters, while maintaining Swagger support.

My use case is that I want to support a JSON API-like set of query parameters such as this:

```
/api/books/?include=author&sort=name,zip&sort[author]=-lname&fields=name,phone,street
```

The use of square brackets prevents me from using traditional classes to model query parameters, so I'm directly using the `Request` object instead. However, I would like to use Swagger to test the endpoint. I can't find a way to provide arbitrary URL parameters. I'm happy to type them in as a single string.

One would think something like the following:

```
def books(**params): 
    ....
```

That gives a curl statement of:

```
api/books?params=sort%5Bone%5D%3Dtwo'
```

what I really want is:

```
api/books?sort&one%5D%3Dtwo'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [Optional](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters) string parameter (`book_params` in the case below) to pass the query parameters as a single string through OpenAPI (Swagger UI) e.g., `include=author&sort=name,zip&sort[author]=-lname&fields=name,phone,street`. You can then parse the query data (using [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)) to get a dictionary, as shown below.

The below example also utilises the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024164/17865804), in order to fix the part where `parse_qs` parses single values into lists (e.g., `'foo=bar'` would be parsed into `foo = ['bar']`), while also preserving all the values for keys that the user passes a list. For example, if the user passed the same key multiple times in the URL, that is, for instance, `'foo=2&bar=7&foo=10'`, using `dict(request.query_params)` to retrieve the query parameters would result in `{"foo":"10","bar":"7"}` instead of `{"foo":["2","10"],"bar":"7"}`. The approach, however, demonstrated in the example below (using the aforementioned method) takes care of that as well, by parsing the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (which can be retieved using `request.url.query`) and makes sure that actual lists are preserved.

You can check whether this optional parameter, i.e., `book_params`, is empty or not to decide whether to read the query params using `book_params` (meaning that the request is sent through Swagger) or using the `Request` object directly (meaning that the request is sent through typing the URL into the address bar of the browser e.g., `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/books?include=author&sort=name,zip&sort[author]=-lname&fields=name,phone,street`, or using some other client app). Please make sure to name that optional parameter (i.e., `book_params`) something unique, which wouldn't also be part of the actual parameters.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from typing import Optional
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/books")
def books(request: Request, book_params: Optional[str] = None):
    q_params = {}
    
    if book_params is not None:
        q_params = parse_qs(book_params, keep_blank_values=True)
    else:   
        q_params = parse_qs(request.url.query, keep_blank_values=True)
        
    d = dict((k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0]) 
                for k, v in q_params.items())

    return d
```

Comment: Interesting, Chris --thanks for the input. I'll give this some thought, it isn't an exact match but may be close enough to be usable.