# How to get current path in FastAPI with domain?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a simple route as below that written in FastAPI,

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/foo/bar/{rand_int}/foo-bar/")
async def main(rand_int: int):
    return {"path": f"https://some-domain.com/foo/bar/{rand_int}/foo-bar/?somethig=foo"}
```

How can I get the current path *"programmatically"* with,

- domain (`some-domain.com`)
- path (`/foo/bar/{rand_int}/foo-bar/`)
- and query parameters (`?somethig=foo`)

Comment: People looking for how to get the raw URL path, for instance, `/foo/bar/{rand_int}/foo-bar/` instead of `/foo/bar/1/foo-bar/`, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72239186/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We can use the [**`Request.url`**-(starlette doc)](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#url) API to get the various URL properties. To get the absolute URL, we need to use the `Request.url._url` private API  ( or `str(Request.url)`), as below

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/foo/bar/{rand_int}/foo-bar/")
async def main(rand_int: int, request: Request):
    return {"raw_url": str(request.url)}
```

Comment: It's also possible to call `str(request.url)` to get an string of the url to avoid accessing a private variable.

Comment: @Abbas Good point, much more pythonic. I use it in f-strings, e.g. `f"{request.url}: {some_log_message}"`.

Answer (score 3):

In latest version of FastAPI (0.103.1)

using `Request` module from `from fastapi import Request` we can get the domain, path and query params

using

```
domain = request.base_url
path = request.url.path
query_params = request.query_params
```

example would be

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/foo/bar/{rand_int}/foo-bar/")
async def main(rand_int: int, request: Request):
    domain = request.base_url
    path = request.url.path
    query_params = request.query_params

    return {"domain": domain, "path": path, "query_params": query_params}
```

Comment: Note that for query parameters, if you expect multiple values for a certain key, using `dict(request.query_params)` wouldn't work as expected. Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) for more details and solutions.

Comment: yes, didn't thought of that case, was encounter with this problem today so give this solution. for that case your provided solution will work or need to write custom parser for that not default one