# How to retrieve query parameter from URL after RedirectResponse in FastAPI?

Tags: python, redirect, oauth, fastapi

I'm implementing an oauth autorization code flow.

What I want is to retrieve the `code` that shows in the url after redirection. I've made researches but haven't found something really helpful. I think that if I can get the current url in the browser after the `RedirectResponse`, I can then extract the `code` parameter of it with python module like `urllib.parse`. Or, does FastApi have a way to help me get that url after the `RedirectResponse`? I saw on their documentation the [Background Tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) but I don't know if that can actually help me retrieve the url after the redirection. I tried using `selenium` library after having seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479543/11209060) but it opens up a new window and when I try to apply the `driver.get('put_your_site_name')` suggested in the comments, it just takes too long.

Here's the code excerpt which is redirecting me to the url in the browser with the code as a parameter :

```
from uuid import uuid4

from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient

from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Response

from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse



router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/install/")
async def install(request: Request) -> Response:
    """Trigger the client identification process."""
    client_id = "xxx"
    client = WebApplicationClient(client_id)
    state = str(uuid4())

    authorization_url = f"https://api-url.com/auth/authorize?client_id={client_id}"
    url = client.prepare_request_uri(
        authorization_url,
        redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/",
        scope=["read:user"],
        state=state,
    )

    return RedirectResponse(url=url)
```

With the above, I'm redirected to the callback url with the authorization code as parameter : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/?code=random-string-xyz`.
I found also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477787/how-to-get-current-path-in-fastapi-with-domain) which is quite close to what I'm looking for, except I'm trying to get the current path only after the redirection.

I've also checked [FastApi query parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) part and tried with the following :

```
import typing
from uuid import uuid4

from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient

from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Response

from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse



router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/install/")
async def install(request: Request, code : typing.Optional[str] = None) -> Response:
    """Trigger the client identification process."""
    client_id = "xxx"
    client = WebApplicationClient(client_id)
    state = str(uuid4())

    authorization_url = f"https://api-url.com/auth/authorize?client_id={client_id}"
    url = client.prepare_request_uri(
        authorization_url,
        redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/",
        scope=["read:user"],
        state=state,
    )


    print("\n code : ", code, "\n")
    return RedirectResponse(url=url)
```

Output : `code : None`, as the code is returned after the redirection I guess?

How do I get that url programmatically to retrieve then the `code`? Or maybe do you have any other way to get it ..?

Comment: My bad, this was pretty obvious. I hadn't been very mindful. This is easily done through query params on the callback endpoint. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead retrieve the value of the `code` parameter inside the `/callback`, not `/install`, endpoint, since that is the endpoint to which you are being redirected—according to the link provided in your question:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/?code=random-string-xyz
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

In FastAPI, you can get query parameters by declaring the parameters in your endpoint. As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) :

> When you declare other function parameters that are not part of the
> path parameters, they are **automatically** interpreted as "query"
> parameters.

Example:

```
@router.get("/callback")
async def install(code : str = None):
    # ...
```

Alternatively, you can [use Starlette's `Request` object directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/) (see Starlette's [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#query-parameters) as well), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72739837/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804).