# How to parse subdomains from URLs in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, subdomain, starlette, parse-url

Our customers are going to hit our new API at  `foo123.bar456.domain.com/v1.5/`

The `foo123` and `bar456` subdomains are account-specific (and let us load balance). They signify relationships and trigger processing we need to do.

We don't want to (repetitively) pass query parameters in the ULR, as in `....domain.com/v1.5/?acc=foo123&parent=bar456`, as that is just non-pythonic, frankly.

So, I'd like to parse, in FastAPI, the fully-qualified domain name that was called.

I can't find tips on how to do this (URL parsing) that doesn't involve folders to the right of the fqdn.  Tips / pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477788/11612918). If I were you, I'd spearate it into a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You could call [`urllib.parse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) on [`request.url`](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#url) to get the hostname/domain name, and then further break it down as desired—inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70658754/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804).

#### Example

Using the example below, when typing, for instance, `http://abc.def.localhost:8000/` in the address bar of the browser and hitting enter, it would return `abc.def.localhost`.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import urllib


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    url = urllib.parse.urlparse(str(request.url))
    return url.hostname
```

You could also further [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the `hostname`, using *dot* (`.`) as the delimiter, in order to get the subdomains. Using the URL provided earlier, the example below would return `["abc","def"]`. Example:

```py
@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    url = urllib.parse.urlparse(str(request.url))
    subs = url.hostname.split('.')
    return subs[:-1]
```

### Update

One does not really have to use `urllib.parse.urlparse()`, in order to get the `hostname`. They could instead use `request.url.hostname`. Hence, the updated example would look like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    subs = request.url.hostname.split('.')
    return subs[:-1]
```

Note that if the `hostname`, instead of `abc.def.localhost`, was, for instance, `abc.def.example.com`, you would then have to use `subs[:-2]` in the example above, in order to exclude the top and second level domains (i.e., `com` and `example`)  from the list of subdomains.