# How do I get my FastAPI application's console log in JSON format with a different structure and different fields?

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI application where I would like to get the default logs written to the STDOUT with the following data in JSON format:

**App logs should look like this:**

```
{
 "XYZ": {
   "log": {
     "level": "info",
     "type": "app",
     "timestamp": "2022-01-16T08:30:08.181Z",
     "file": "api/predictor/predict.py",
     "line": 34,
     "threadId": 435454,
     "message": "API Server started on port 8080 (development)"
    }
  }
}
```

**Access logs should look like this:**

```
{
 "XYZ": {
   "log": {
     "level": "info",
     "type": "access",
     "timestamp": "2022-01-16T08:30:08.181Z",
     "message": "GET /app/health 200 6ms"
   },
   "req": {
     "url": "/app/health",
     "headers": {
       "host": "localhost:8080",
       "user-agent": "curl/7.68.0",
       "accept": "*/*"
     },
     "method": "GET",
     "httpVersion": "1.1",
     "originalUrl": "/app/health",
     "query": {}
   },
   "res": {
     "statusCode": 200,
     "body": {
       "statusCode": 200,
       "status": "OK"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What I've tried**

I tried using the [`json-logging`](https://github.com/bobbui/json-logging-python) package for this. Using [this](https://github.com/bobbui/json-logging-python/blob/master/example/custom_log_format_request.py) example, I'm able to access the request logs in json and change the structure. But I'm unable to find how to access and change the app logs.

**Current output logs structure**

```
{"written_at": "2022-01-28T09:31:38.686Z", "written_ts": 1643362298686910000, "msg": 
"Started server process [12919]", "type": "log", "logger": "uvicorn.error", "thread": 
"MainThread", "level": "INFO", "module": "server", "line_no": 82, "correlation_id": 
"-"}

{"written_at": "2022-01-28T09:31:38.739Z", "written_ts": 1643362298739838000, "msg": 
"Started server process [12919]", "type": "log", "logger": "uvicorn.error", "thread": 
"MainThread", "level": "INFO", "module": "server", "line_no": 82, "correlation_id": 
"-"}

{"written_at": "2022-01-28T09:31:38.739Z", "written_ts": 1643362298739951000, "msg": 
"Waiting for application startup.", "type": "log", "logger": "uvicorn.error", 
"thread": "MainThread", "level": "INFO", "module": "on", "line_no": 45, 
"correlation_id": "-"}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do that by creating a custom [Formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) using the built-in logger module. You can use the `extra` parameter when logging messages to pass contextual information, such as url and headers. [Python's JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) already implements pretty-printing JSON data in the [`dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) function, using the `indent` parameter that allows you to define the indent level. Below is a working example using a custom formatter to log messages in the format you described in your question. For "App" logs use, for instance, `logger.info('sample log message')`, whereas, for "Access" logs, use `logger.info('sample log message', extra={'extra_info': get_extra_info(request)})`. By passing the `request` instance to the `get_extra_info()` method, you can extract information such as the one you mentioned above. For more `LogRecord` attributes, have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes). The below example uses a `FileHandler` for logging the messages to a log file on disk as well. If you don't need that, you can comment it out in the `get_logger()` method.

The approach below uses a [FastAPI `Middleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/) to log requests/responses, which allows you to handle the `request` before it is processed by some specific endpoint, as well as the `response`, before it is returned to the client. Additionally, the approach demonstrated below uses a [`BackgroundTask`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) for logging the data (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804)). A background task *"will run only once the response has been sent"* (as per [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/background/)), meaning that client won't have to  be waiting for the logging to complete before receiving the response. See this [**related answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) as well.

**app_logger.py**

```py
import logging, sys


def get_file_handler(formatter, log_filename):
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    return file_handler


def get_stream_handler(formatter):
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    return stream_handler


def get_logger(name, formatter, log_filename = "logfile.log"):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(get_file_handler(formatter, log_filename))
    logger.addHandler(get_stream_handler(formatter))
    return logger
```

**app_logger_formatter.py**

```py
import json, logging


def get_app_log(record):
    json_obj = {'XYZ': {'log': {
        'level': record.levelname,
        'type': 'app',
        'timestamp': record.asctime,
        #'filename': record.filename,
        'pathname': record.pathname,
        'line': record.lineno,
        'threadId': record.thread,
        'message': record.message
        }}}

    return json_obj


def get_access_log(record):
    json_obj = {'XYZ': {'log': {
        'level': record.levelname,
        'type': 'access',
        'timestamp': record.asctime,
        'message': record.message},
        'req': record.extra_info['req'],
        'res': record.extra_info['res']}}

    return json_obj


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def __init__(self, formatter):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, formatter)
    
    def format(self, record):
        logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        if not hasattr(record, 'extra_info'):
            return json.dumps(get_app_log(record), indent=2)
        else:
            return json.dumps(get_access_log(record), indent=2)
```

**app.py**

```py
import app_logger
from app_logger_formatter import CustomFormatter
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from http import HTTPStatus
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
formatter = CustomFormatter('%(asctime)s')
logger = app_logger.get_logger(__name__, formatter)
status_reasons = {x.value:x.name for x in list(HTTPStatus)}

def get_extra_info(request: Request, response: Response):
    return {'req': {
        'url': request.url.path,
        'headers': {'host': request.headers['host'],
                    'user-agent': request.headers['user-agent'],
                    'accept': request.headers['accept']},
        'method': request.method,
        'httpVersion': request.scope['http_version'],
        'originalUrl': request.url.path,
        'query': {}
        },
        'res': {'statusCode': response.status_code, 'body': {'statusCode': response.status_code,
                   'status': status_reasons.get(response.status_code)}}}

def write_log_data(request, response):
    logger.info(request.method + ' ' + request.url.path, extra={'extra_info': get_extra_info(request, response)})

@app.middleware("http")
async def log_request(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    response.background = BackgroundTask(write_log_data, request, response)
    return response

@app.get("/foo")
def foo(request: Request):
    return "success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("Server started listening on port: 8000")
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**Output**:

```
{
  "XYZ": {
    "log": {
      "level": "INFO",
      "type": "app",
      "timestamp": "2022-01-28 10:46:01,904",
      "pathname": ".../app.py",
      "line": 33,
      "threadId": 408,
      "message": "Server started listening on port: 8000"
    }
  }
}
{
  "XYZ": {
    "log": {
      "level": "INFO",
      "type": "access",
      "timestamp": "2022-01-28 10:46:03,587",
      "message": "GET /foo"
    },
    "req": {
      "url": "/foo",
      "headers": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1:8000",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 ...",
        "accept": "text/html,..."
      },
      "method": "GET",
      "httpVersion": "1.1",
      "originalUrl": "/foo",
      "query": {}
    },
    "res": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "body": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "status": "OK"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer @Chris, thank you!
One question: how can I return the request query and response content inside the json?

Comment: @SinkThor Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883126/17865804).

Comment: Response works perfectly, however the request_body always comes empty event though I send params as a query argument (i.e. /api/resource?parameter=value )

Comment: @SinkThor If there is no body in the request you sent, this is normal. Request body refers to data sent by the client in the _body_, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804). You should expect to see query parameters in the URL, which you can retrieve similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72739837/17865804).

Comment: Very nice solution, question: how to response body to those logs ? Tried multiple options like those from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882419/fastapi-how-to-get-the-response-body-in-middleware but can not make it working

Comment: @user2913139 Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) as well.

Comment: This is stellar, plug and play with a FastAPI service.

Comment: Could you explain the `call_next` parameter you added to the middleware function?

Comment: @Jhirschibar Please have a look at the [relevant documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/#create-a-middleware)