# FastAPI does not return the response after done processing the request

Tags: docker, httpresponse, fastapi

I have this weird problem, normally I deployed an API using FastAPI inside a docker, my configuration is like below:

```
command: bash -c "wait-for my_services_container:50005 -- uvicorn rest_api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9001"
```

Now suddenly, the API doesn't return any response, I checked logs and see it still processes incoming requests (just doesn't return results).

I logged into the docker and call localhost:9001, still the same, so I guess it's not about docker port mapping, something to do with FastAPI and Uvicorn. Anyway, does anyone get an idea where to check? Thanks

Comment: Whats your ouput when you run a command line version of the request, (not the browser), use curl, wget or httpie

Comment: can you send the boot file : `server.py` or `app.py` (or whatever you called it) that contains the different routes ?

Comment: Sorry, I found a problem with my DB call. I update DB after completing the process and before returning the response. And it hangs when updating DB.

Comment: You could use a `BakcgroundTask`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221061/17865804).