# FastAPI/Starlette: How to handle exceptions inside background tasks?

Tags: python, exception, fastapi, background-task, starlette

I developed some API endpoints using FastAPI. These endpoints are allowed to run `BackgroundTasks`. Unfortunately, I do not know how to handle unpredictable issues from theses tasks.

An example of my API is shown below:

```py
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn


app = FastAPI()


def test_func(a, b):
    raise ...


@app.post("/test", status_code=201)
async def test(request: Request, background_task: BackgroundTasks):
    background_task.add_task(test_func, a, b)
    return {
        "message": "The test task was successfully sent.",
    }
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        app=app,
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8000
    )
# python3 main.py to run
# fastapi == 0.78.0
# uvicorn == 0.16.0
```

Can you help me to handle any type of exception from such a background task?
Should I add any `exception_middleware` from Starlette, in order to achieve this?

Comment: why you can't use `try / except` statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Can you help me to handle **any type** of exception from such a background task?*

[`Background tasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), as the name suggests, are tasks that are going to run in the background **after** returning a response. Hence, you can't `raise` an `Exception` and expect the client to receive some kind of response. If you are just looking to catch **any** `Exception` occuring inside the background task, you can simply use the `try-except` block to catch any [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) and handle it as desired. For example:

```py
def test_func(a, b):
    try:
        # some background task logic here...
        raise <some_exception>
    except Exception as e:
        print('Something went wrong')
        # use `print(e.detail)` to print out the Exception's details
```

If you would like to log any exceptions being raised in the task (instead of just printing them out), you could use Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module—have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221061/17865804) on how to do that. You may also find helpful information on FastAPI/Starlette's custom/global exception handlers at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804).

Finally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) will help you understand in detail the difference between `def` and `async def` endpoints (as well as background task functions) in FastAPI, and find solutions for tasks blocking the `event loop` (if you ever come across this issue).

Comment: Okay. Thank you a lot :) 
I was not aware about good practices to handle background tasks error.
I will develop an entire logging system for the API.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "unpredictable errors"and what would be the behavior if an exception occurs?

A try/except statement could work.

```
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn


app = FastAPI()


def test_func(a, b):
    raise ...


@app.post("/test", status_code=201)
async def test(request: Request, background_task: BackgroundTasks):
    try:
        background_task.add_task(test_func, a, b)
        return {
            "message": "The test task was successfully sent.",
        }
    except Exception as e:
        # exception handling code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        app=app,
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8000
    )
# python3 main.py to run
# fastapi == 0.78.0
# uvicorn == 0.16.0
```