# In FastAPI, how do you return a StreamingResponse, but also do something after the streaming is done?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, streamingresponsebody

In my FastAPI route, I need to return a `StreamingResponse` to the user as each chunk of a text sentence gets generated.

However, the complete text sentence needs to be inserted into a database. Is there a way to do this?

```
@app.post("/foo_stream")
def foo_stream(input: Input, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return StreamingResponse(
        generate_streaming_response(input),
        media_type="text/plain",
    )

    # Now that the streaming is done, how do you insert the entire text into our database?
```

Comment: You could have the `response` stored in a variable and use a `BackgroundTask` for saving it to the database - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221061/17865804). If you would like having a middleware for this task, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804)