# FastAPI stuck on Waiting for application startup

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi

I'm trying to create a web app using FastAPI, to show weather and time and Bitcoin price and etc. This is the Python code (I obviously replace the `OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY` and other stuff):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect, BackgroundTasks
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
import requests
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

# Templates
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

# Static files (like CSS and JS)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

# API key for OpenWeatherMap (replace with your own)
OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY = "YOUR_OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY"

# Background task to update Bitcoin price every minute
async def update_bitcoin_price(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        bitcoin_price = get_bitcoin_price()
        background_tasks.add_task(update_data, "bitcoinPrice", f"Bitcoin Price: €{bitcoin_price}")

# Background task to update weather information every 5 minutes
async def update_weather_info(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(300)
        weather_info = get_weather_info()
        background_tasks.add_task(update_data, "weatherInfo", weather_info)

# Background task to update text file contents every 4 hours
async def update_file_contents(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(14400)
        file_contents = get_file_contents()
        background_tasks.add_task(update_data, "fileContents", f"Text File Contents: {file_contents}")

# Function to fetch Bitcoin price from CoinGecko API
def get_bitcoin_price():
    response = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=eur')
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    return data["bitcoin"]["eur"]

# Function to fetch weather information from OpenWeatherMap API
def get_weather_info():
    city = "YOUR_CITY"  # Replace with the city of your choice
    weather_endpoint = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY}&units=metric"
    response = requests.get(weather_endpoint)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    temperature = data["main"]["temp"]
    weather_description = data["weather"][0]["description"]
    return f"Weather: {weather_description}, Temperature: {temperature}°C"

# Function to fetch text file contents
def get_file_contents():
    try:
        with open("your_text_file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "Text file not found"

# Function to update data on the web page
def update_data(data_id: str, new_data: str):
    sockets_to_update = list(app.state.websockets)
    for socket in sockets_to_update:
        socket["background_tasks"].add_task(emit_data, socket["websocket"], data_id, new_data)

# Function to emit data to connected clients
async def emit_data(websocket, data_id: str, new_data: str):
    await websocket.send_text(f'{{"id": "{data_id}", "data": "{new_data}"}}')

# Route to handle the WebSocket connection
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    app.state.websockets.add({"websocket": websocket, "background_tasks": BackgroundTasks()})
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        app.state.websockets.remove({"websocket": websocket, "background_tasks": BackgroundTasks()})

# Route to render the HTML page
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_item(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

# Start background tasks
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    app.websockets = set()
    background_tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    background_tasks.add_task(update_bitcoin_price)
    background_tasks.add_task(update_weather_info)
    background_tasks.add_task(update_file_contents)
    app.add_event_handler("startup", startup_event)

# Serve the app using Uvicorn
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

And this is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FastAPI Web App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            color: green;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #time {
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #bitcoinPrice {
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        #additionalText {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

        #weatherInfo {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        #fileContents {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, this is a FastAPI web app with live time, Bitcoin price, weather information, and text file contents!</h1>
    <p>This is a simple web app with styling, live time, live Bitcoin price in euros, weather information, and text file contents using FastAPI.</p>

    <div id="time"></div>
    <div id="bitcoinPrice"></div>
    <div id="weatherInfo"></div>
    <div id="fileContents"></div>

    <script>
        // WebSocket connection
        const socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws");

        // Function to update data on the web page
        function updateData(data) {
            const element = document.getElementById(data.id);
            if (element) {
                element.innerHTML = data.data;
            }
        }

        // Event listener for WebSocket messages
        socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            updateData(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app (using `uvicorn main:app --reload`) I get this in the console:

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users...']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [14632] using WatchFiles              
INFO:     Started server process [9072]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
```

And that's it. Nothing happens. And if Visit http://127.0.0.1:8000, I get this error:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your host and port in code is different than one showing in the konsole

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thank you. I corrected that. Now everything is 127.0.0.1:8000. But still the same problem.

Comment: try to comment the code in the startup_event and check if the server runs correctly(just print hello or something else) if it works then we can identify that the problem is being caused the background tasks, try that and let's see, so I can provide a solution.

Comment: In addition to the links provided in the banner above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804). Regarding `BackgroundTasks`, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221061/17865804).

Comment: As [explained by @tiangolo](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/289#issuecomment-503990293), _"background tasks internally depend on a `Request`, and they are executed after returning the request to the client. In the case of a `WebSocket`, as the `WebSocket` is not really "finished" but is an ongoing connection, it wouldn't be a background task"_. You could, however, have functions executed in the background, using one of the options described in the second link above (if it is an `async` function, preferably use `asyncio.create_task()`)

Comment: @notrayen Thank you very much. I did comment out the startup_event, and indeed the server came up and the static text was shown without any problem. Great advice! How do you think I can go about fixing this problem? What is wrong with those background tasks?

Comment: @kalike5373 Chris comment explains everything. try it out.