# How to run a Background Task when using websockets in FastAPI/Starlette?

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi, background-task, starlette

**My ultimate goal** is to write code that only triggers other servers when calling an endpoint and waits for data from a specific channel in Redis to come in. I don't want to know external server's business logic is done due to latency.

The `call_external_server` background task function below will notify the external server to send data to Redis (pub/sub). However, it doesn't execute.

Here is my code:

```py
async def call_external_server(channel, text):
    print("call_external_server start")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f"http://localhost:9000/pub?channel={channel}&text={text}") as resp:
            print(resp)
    print("call_external_server finished")
    return {"response": "external_server is done"}


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(channel: str, websocket: WebSocket, background_task: BackgroundTasks):
    await websocket.accept()
    client_info = dict(websocket.headers)
    text = client_info.get("text")
    redis_reader: redis.client.PubSub = await get_redis_pubsub()
    await redis_reader.subscribe(channel)
    

    # Problem is Here 
    background_task.add_task(call_external_server, channel, text)
    # Background task Doesn't work properly 

    try:
        while True:
            message = await redis_reader.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
            if message is not None:
                decoded_msg = message["data"].decode()
                if decoded_msg == STOPWORD:
                    print("(Reader) STOP")
                    break
                await websocket.send_text(decoded_msg)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await websocket.close()
        return
    await websocket.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BackgroundTask` is executed **after** returning a response to a client's `request` (**not** on ongoing `websocket` connections)—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221061/17865804) and this [related comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76279889/how-to-use-background-tasks-inside-a-function-that-is-called-by-a-fastapi-endpoi/76280152#comment137407145_76280152) for more details on Background Tasks. As [explained by @tiangolo](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/289#issuecomment-503990293) (the creator of FastAPI):

> Background Tasks internally **depend on a `Request`**, and they are
> executed **after** returning the request to the client. In the case of a
> `WebSocket`, as the `WebSocket` is not really "finished" but **is an
> ongoing connection**, it wouldn't be a background task.

You could, however, have functions executed in the background, using one of the options described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804). If your background task is an `async def` function, you should rather use Option 3 (see the linked answer above for more details), i.e., using `asyncio.create_task()`. Have a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) as well.

### Example

```py
async def call_external_server(channel, text):
    pass


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
   await websocket.accept()
   # ...
   asyncio.create_task(call_external_server(channel, text))
```

I would also suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308268/17865804) on how to spawn an HTTP Client **once** at application startup and **reuse** it every time is needed, instead of creating a new connection every time the endpoint is called (as shown in the example provided in your question).