# Upload File operation using FastAPI does not work on Deta Cloud Platform

Tags: python, cloud, web-deployment, fastapi

When I run this code via `uvicorn main:app` everything works, but when I run it using Deta, I get `Internal Server Error` and only `GET` endpoint works (the `POST` one is not even called as it was supposed to).
Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, HTMLResponse

from pdfpad import pdfpad, save_pdf


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/processfile/")
async def process_file(file: UploadFile) -> FileResponse:
    path = file.filename
    if os.getenv("DETA_RUNTIME") == "true":
        path = Path("/tmp") / file.filename
    saved_path = save_pdf(pdfpad(await file.read()), path)
    return FileResponse(saved_path)


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    content = """
        <body>
        <form action="/processfile/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form1">
        
        <label for file>Choose PDF:</label>
        file: <input name="file" type="file" form="form1">
        <br><br>
        
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
        </body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Deta is very restrictive. As shown in the [Technical Specifications](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/micros/about/#technical-specifications), Deta Micros (micro servers) provide a **read-only** file system, only `/tmp` can be written to, which has a 512 MB storage limit.

Deta provides two additional services, i.e., [Deta Base](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/base/about) (a fully-managed, NoSQL database, which you can use to store, query, update and delete records in the database) and [Deta Drive](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/drive/about/) (a scalable file storage service, which you can use to upload and store files).

Deta Drive is the one you should be looking for in your case. However, as per the [documentation](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/micros/about/#technical-specifications), Deta Micros have HTTP payload size limit of 5.5 MB, meaning that if you would like to upload a file that is larger than 5.5 MB, you can't—unless you upload the file to your API in chunks of 5.5 MB, and then from your API re-upload the file to Deta Drive, using [this endpoint](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/drive/http#put-file) if the file size is less than 10 MB; otherwise, if the file is larger than 10 MB, you would have to upload the file in chunks, using [chunked upload](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/drive/http#initialize-chunked-upload). As per [Upload Chunked Part](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/drive/http#upload-chunked-part):

> Each chunk must be at least 5 Mb and at most 10 Mb. The final chunk
> can be less than 5 Mb.

From the code snippet you provided, you seem to be writing the file to the `/tmp` directory, using `Path` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module. Please try specifying the path without using the `pathlib` module, as well as try specifying the directory with `./` at the start, for example:

```py
path = Path("./tmp") / file.filename
```

You said that you get an `Internal Server Error`, which is a very generic error and says little about the nature of the error. You should instead take a look at the actual log from your service (`logging` example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804)), which would tell what is causing the app to fail. If you provided the full traceback, it would really help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The error occured due to absence of `poppler-utils` and has nothing to do with FastApi.

My program requires linux package `poppler-utils` to process pdf files. Since Deta cloud does not have one and does not allow users to execute any `... apt install ...` commands, aforementioned error occured.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: edited, sorry for delay