# FastAPI console log with request + response body

Tags: fastapi

I am running fastAPI with the logging proposed here: [How do I get my FastAPI application's console log in JSON format with a different structure and different fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891687/how-do-i-get-my-fastapi-applications-console-log-in-json-format-with-a-differen)

And tried to add another log: response + request payload/body like this (in get_extra_info()):

```
response_body = b""
for chunk in response.body_iterator:
   response_body += chunk
```

But when running getting error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1100, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 943, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/home/mgarcarz/scripts/fastapi/./utils/app_logger_formatter.py", line 41, in format
    return json.dumps(get_access_log(record), indent=2)
  File "/home/mgarcarz/scripts/fastapi/./utils/app_logger_formatter.py", line 25, in get_access_log
    'req': record.extra_info['req'],
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
```

When i tried this example: [How to log raw HTTP request/response in Python FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670125/how-to-log-raw-http-request-response-in-python-fastapi/73464007#73464007)

Request body is logged correctly, but for response body i got error:

```
File "/home/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-0fqfDXdY/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 269, in wrap
    await func()
  File "/home/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-0fqfDXdY/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 263, in stream_response
    await send({"type": "http.response.body", "body": b"", "more_body": False})
  File "/home/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-0fqfDXdY/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in _send
    await send(message)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-0fqfDXdY/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 561, in send
    raise RuntimeError("Response content shorter than Content-Length")
RuntimeError: Response content shorter than Content-Length
```

Any ideas how to get it fixed ?

Thanks,

Comment: Hard to tell since you haven't provided enough information, but I suspect it's because you haven't awaited the response. Could you paste how you are accessing the response object?