# Minimal configuration for uvicorn/fastapi logs in JSON format without being colorized

Tags: json, logging, python-logging, uvicorn

The following approach gets close to the result [Format string output to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590705/format-string-output-to-json), but one issue is the "color_messsage" field which leads to special color characters to be part of the json logs

{"message": "Finished server process [54894]", "color_message": "Finished server process [\u001b[36m%d\u001b[0m]"}

Any recommended way to either drop the "color_message". An option could be to subclass the `pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter` and pop the color messages but this seems a bit hacky.

Any recommendation?

Tried the same setup as here but with uvicorn only: [Format string output to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590705/format-string-output-to-json)

I also tried setting the --no-use-colors but as the documentation mentions (https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging) this option is not set when we specify a logging config file.