# How to configure FastAPI logging so that it works both with Uvicorn locally and in production?

Tags: python, logging, fastapi

I have an api.py file with the following:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import logging
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI(title="api")

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.info("API is starting up")
LOG.info(uvicorn.Config.asgi_version)

@app.get("/")
async def get_index():
    LOG.info("GET /"
    return {"Hello": "Api"}
```

The application locally is run with:

```
uvicorn api:app --reload
```

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/user/code/backend/api']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [44258] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [44260]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

It is not logging any of the startup messages.

Later on when sending a http request to the api:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50538 - "POST /api/v1/endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

In the function body there is LOG.info("example") that does not get logged either.

Is there a way to make FastAPI logging work with Uvicorn and also in production (independently of the execution environments like Uvicorn).

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) helpful.

Comment: thanks @chris these are helpful but do not solve my problem.

Comment: To log startup messages, please try using a `startup`/`lifespan` event handler, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804)

Comment: I think this is a working reproducible example now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to add a `StreamHandler` and/or `FileHandler` and set the level/severity (i.e., `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, etc). The following example is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804). More details and examples can be found in Python's official documentation page [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). You may also want to have a look at all the available [`LogRecord` attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) that can be used to format the logging records.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import logging
import sys


app = FastAPI(title='api')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(processName)s: %(process)d] [%(threadName)s: %(thread)d] [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s")
stream_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.info('API is starting up')


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    logger.info('GET /')
    return 'ok'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another thing I added here is a message formatter.
Instead of 
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
I added
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

Comment: @AnnGuseva Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804) (given in the answer above as well) on how to further customise the log messages.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at how uvicorn set its loggers in the recent versions I came up with this:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('uvicorn.error')

@app.get('/')
async def main():
    logger.debug('this is a debug message')
    return 'ok'
```

The log level is controlled by the uvicorn command line option `--log-level debug` and produces:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
DEBUG:    this is a debug message
```