# fastapi a simple function greet(*args) sdf

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter

I have simple function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments like so:

```py
def greet(*args):
    a=list(args)
    return {"greetings to  users:": a}

greet('Aron','Claus')
>>>{'greetings to  users:': ['Aron', 'Claus']}
```

The function works as expected. But when i put a router decorator on the function like so:

```py
@router.get("/greet")
def greet(*args):
    a=list(args)
    return {"greetings to  users:": a}
```

I get an internal server error on swagger side and my commandline gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: greet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Why is this happening how can I avoid this error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you expecting `args` to represented in a web context? How are you expecting to pass this value through web?

Comment: I am new to web development. I want to pass a list of arbitrary length to the greet function and thought it would be most concise to use `args`

Comment: Yes, but _where are these arguments coming from_. Since you want to expose this through FastAPI, these arguments are apparently coming from a web context. So how do you want to invoke `greet` from the web, and how are you planning on providing those arguments through a web service? This is important since you have to define _how the arguments should be provided_ when you expose a function as route function; are these provided as GET parameters in the URL  (`/path?foo=bar&baz=bar`), as POST parameters or submitted as JSON? You can't define a "catch all" argument in this way then, since FastAPI

Comment: .. needs you to give it some information about _where_ the parameters should come from and what their expected type is - so that it can validate the request for you and convert the values into the expected format for your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow any arbitrary query parameters using FastAPI and Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821077/how-to-allow-any-arbitrary-query-parameters-using-fastapi-and-swagger)

Comment: Additionally, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804) on how to submit JSON data to a FastAPI backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i found is the following from the [Fastapi documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values/)

```py
from typing import List, Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: Union[List[str], None] = Query(default=None)):
    query_items = {"q": q}
    return query_items
```

The URL would be like:
`http://localhost:8000/items/?q=foo&q=bar`

It works fine.