# Access data in dictionary returned by urllib method

Tags: python, post, request, urllib, wsgi

I'm a Python newbie, so I beg your pardon if this may eventually sound too basic.

With this code:

```
 with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        
        request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read().decode()
        d = urllib.parse.parse_qs(request_body, True)
        print(d, file=f)
```

I write to a file the following dictionary:

```
{b'--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data': [b''], b' name': [b'"username"\r\n\r\nuser1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', b'"password"\r\n\r\npassuser1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', b'"gender"\r\n\r\n1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995--\r\n']}
```

Problem is I don't know how to access its content.

I need to read the POST fields data, `username`, `password` and `gender`.

I tried `d.get("username")` and similar solutions but result was `None`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you post data is stored 'data' variable

```
data = {b'--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data': [b''], b' name': [b'"username"\r\n\r\nuser1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', b'"password"\r\n\r\npassuser1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', b'"gender"\r\n\r\n1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995--\r\n']}

username = data[b' name'][0]
password = data[b' name'][1]
gender = data[b' name'][2]

print(username.decode().split("\n")[2])
print(password.decode().split("\n")[2])
print(gender.decode().split("\n")[2])
```

This should fetch your required data

```
>>> data = {b'--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data': [b''], b' name': [b'"username"\r\n\r\nuser1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', b'"password"\r\n\r\npassuser1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', b'"gender"\r\n\r\n1\r\n--------------------------a7beefa9095fb995--\r\n']}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print(username.decode().split("\n")[2])
user1
>>> print(password.decode().split("\n")[2])
passuser1
>>> print(gender.decode().split("\n")[2])
1
>>>
```

Hope this helps.. But i think there must be some other better ways to get it by cleaning the post data that you provided.

Comment: I agree with you, but I couldn't find a way to parse that "thing". From your code I got this error: d[b' name'][0] KeyError: b' name'. 

It doesn't like the way the key is accessed

Comment: Ok, it works this way, instead: username = d[' name'][0] and then u = username.split("\n")[2] (removing decode). BUT, you're right, there must be something else to process this POST, I've never seen something so complicated for a very simple task like this.

Comment: I tried the Amine solution here, but it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530526/accessing-post-data-from-wsgi (I get 'None' when accessing username and other fields)